# Formatting Datetime in SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Part of my query is like so:

```
    SELECT * FROM TableA
    WHERE ColumnA  >= DATEADD(DAY, - 30, GETDATE())
```

With the expression at the where clause above, you can pull a rolling 30 days data without having to supply values. Now users of the report want to see it represented like:

```
    2nd April – 1st May
```

when the report is ran.  Knowing that I have no parameters as the requirement is to not use parameters, how do I reference ">= DATEADD(DAY, - 30, GETDATE())" to reflect the start date and the end date in the report?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format datetime day with st, nd, rd, th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712572/format-datetime-day-with-st-nd-rd-th)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSRS doesn't have built-in support for ordinal numbers (i.e. "1st" or "2nd" instead of "1" or "2"). [This page](http://www.jigsawboys.com/2010/03/04/ordinal-number-in-reporting-services/) contains custom code to add this functionality to your SSRS report; however it is slightly wrong. Here is a corrected version:

```
Public Function FormatOrdinal(ByVal day As Integer) as String
        ' Starts a select case based on the odd/even of num
        if(day = 11 or day = 12 or day = 13)

        ' If the nymber is 11,12 or 13 .. we want to add a "th" NOT a "st", "nd" or "rd"
            return day.ToString() + "th"


        else
    ' Start a new select case for the rest of the numbers
    Select Case day Mod 10
        Case 1
            ' The number is either 1 or 21 .. add a "st"
            Return day.ToString() + "st"
        Case 2
            ' The number is either a 2 or 22 .. add a "nd"
            Return day.ToString() + "nd"
        Case 3
            ' The number is either a 3 or 33 .. add a "rd"
            Return day.ToString() + "rd"
        Case Else
             ' Otherwise for everything else add a "Th"
            Return day.ToString() + "th"
    End Select
        end if
End Function
```

If you add this code to the code section of your report under report properties, your textbox expression would be:

```
Code.FormatOrdinal(Day(Globals!ExecutionTime)) & " " & MonthName(Month(Globals!ExecutionTime), False) & " - " &  Code.FormatOrdinal(Day(DateAdd("d", -30,Globals!ExecutionTime))) & " " & MonthName(Month(DateAdd("d", -30,Globals!ExecutionTime)), False)
```

﻿

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the `Textbox`, Go To `Textbox Properties` then, Click on `Number tab`, click on `custom format` option then click on `fx` button in black.

Write just one line of code will do your work in simpler way:

A form will open, copy the below text and paste there to need to change following text with your database date field.

> Fields!FieldName.Value, "Dataset"

1. Replace `FieldName` with your Date Field
2. Replace `Dataset` with your Dateset Name

   ="d" + switch(int(Day((Fields!FieldName.Value, "Dataset"))) mod 10=1,"'st'",int(Day((Fields!FieldName.Value, "Dataset"))) mod 10 = 2,"'nd'",int(Day((Fields!FieldName.Value, "Dataset"))) mod 10 = 3,"'rd'",true,"'th'") + " MMMM, yyyy"