# How to create ordinal numbers (i.e. "1st" "2nd", etc.) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I recently responded [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163920/formatting-datetime-in-ssrs-expression) in the SSRS-2008 tag that required changing the day number in a date to the ordinal number (i.e. "1st", "2nd" instead of "1", "2"). The solution involved a VB.Net function. I'm curious how one would go about performing this task in SQL (t-sql and SQL Server in particular), or if there is some built in support.

So here is a scenario: say you have organized a footrace for 1000 runners and have the results in a table with the columns Name and Place (in normal numbers). You want to create a query that will display a user's name and their place in ordinal numbers.

Comment: There is no built-in support.  You'll have to create a mapping of ones digit to suffixes (1 -> st, 2 -> nd) and overrides for tens (12 -> th) etc.  It's much easier to do in a reporting/app layer than in SQL.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a scalable solution that should work for any number. I thought other's used % 100 for 11,12,13 but I was mistaken.

```
WITH CTE_Numbers
AS
(
    SELECT 1 num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1
    FROM CTE_Numbers
    WHERE num < 1000
)

SELECT  CAST(num AS VARCHAR(10))
        +
        CASE
            WHEN num % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th' --first checks for exception
            WHEN num % 10 = 1 THEN 'st'
            WHEN num % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd'
            WHEN num % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd'
            ELSE 'th' --works for num % 10 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
        END
FROM CTE_Numbers
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Worked a treat. I just needed correct numerical display in email text and this saved me having to spend time on it. Thanks.

Comment: I happened to come across this post. I don't want to post this as a solution since it's exactly the same as this one, I just happened to write it in a different way using functions that were not available at the time this solution was offered and I'm a huge fan of one liners lol: IIF(num % 100 IN (11,12,13), 'th', COALESCE(CHOOSE(num % 10,'st','nd','rd'),'th'))

Comment: @chadwin I think a one-liner deserves its own answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can do that just as easily in SQL as in the app layer:

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME = '2015-05-21';
DECLARE @day INT;
SELECT  @day = DAY(@myDate);
SELECT  CASE WHEN @day IN ( 11, 12, 13 ) THEN CAST(@day AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'th'
             WHEN @day % 10 = 1 THEN CAST(@day AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'st'
             WHEN @day % 10 = 2 THEN CAST(@day AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'nd'
             WHEN @day % 10 = 3 THEN CAST(@day AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'rd'
             ELSE CAST(@day AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'th'
        END
```

You could also put this in a scalar function if necessary.

**EDIT**

For your example, it would be:

```
SELECT  Name ,
        CASE WHEN Place IN ( 11, 12, 13 )
             THEN CAST(Place AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'th'
             WHEN Place % 10 = 1 THEN CAST(Place AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'st'
             WHEN Place % 10 = 2 THEN CAST(Place AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'nd'
             WHEN Place % 10 = 3 THEN CAST(Place AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'rd'
             ELSE CAST(Place AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'th'
        END AS Place
FROM    FootRaceResults;
```

Comment: Your code would seem to work for dates, but what about the scenario with runners that I presented? What about the 111th place? Any way to code that in a scalable fashion?

Comment: You'd just add that field to your select statement.

Answer (score 4):

Be very afraid:

```
with
  ArabicRomanConversions as (
    select *
      from ( values
        ( 0, '', '', '', '' ), ( 1, 'I', 'X', 'C', 'M' ), ( 2, 'II', 'XX', 'CC', 'MM' ), ( 3, 'III', 'XXX', 'CCC', 'MMM' ), ( 4, 'IV', 'XL', 'CD', '?' ),
        ( 5, 'V', 'L', 'D', '?' ), ( 6, 'VI', 'LX', 'DC', '?' ), ( 7, 'VII', 'LXX', 'DCC', '?' ), ( 8, 'VIII', 'LXXX', 'DCCC', '?' ), ( 9, 'IX', 'XC', 'CM', '?' )
        ) as Placeholder ( Arabic, Ones, Tens, Hundreds, Thousands )
      ),
  OrdinalConversions as (
    select *
      from ( values
        ( 1, 'st' ), ( 2, 'nd' ), ( 3, 'rd' ), ( 11, 'th' ), ( 12, 'th' ), ( 13, 'th' )
        ) as Placeholder2 ( Number, Suffix )
      ),
  Numbers as (
    select 1 as Number
    union all
    select Number + 1
      from Numbers
      where Number < 3999 )
  select Number as Arabic,
    ( select Thousands from ArabicRomanConversions where Arabic = Number / 1000 ) +
    ( select Hundreds from ArabicRomanConversions where Arabic = Number / 100 % 10 ) +
    ( select Tens from ArabicRomanConversions where Arabic = Number / 10 % 10 ) +
    ( select Ones from ArabicRomanConversions where Arabic = Number % 10 ) as Roman,
    Cast( Number as VarChar(4) ) + Coalesce( (
      select top 1 Suffix from OrdinalConversions where Number = Numbers.Number % 100 or Number = Numbers.Number % 10 order by Number desc ), 'th' ) as Ordinal
    from Numbers option ( MaxRecursion 3998 );
```

Comment: Interesting approach and great answer. I noticed the roman numerals bit - is this from a pre-existing source?

Comment: @TPhe - I just grabbed the numbers table CTE that I had added a column for ordinals. If the footrace happened long ago, someone might have come in XLIInd.

Comment: It's very odd that would accept this as the answer considering it's WAY more complicated than it needs to be. Dave Gugg's answer works perfectly and is a fraction of the complexity...

Comment: @Stephan I agree that this answer is needlessly bulky with the extra Roman Numerals stuff in there - that is not useful in the context of my question and would be better edited out. However, Dave Gugg's answer was less scalable and complete than this answer. I asked specifically for a solution that went up to 1000; Dave's answer would work only up to 110 (111 gives you 111st instead of 111th). His proposed extension (just add in special cases for 111,112,113,211,212,213,etc.) would be more work and less scalable than this answer. Both answers are useful; upvoted both.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a case statement, I.e.,

UPDATE: Taking into account the teens, as mentioned by TPhe and refactored slightly.

```
SELECT
    Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN Place in(11, 12, 13) then CAST(Place as VARCHAR(20)) + 'th'
        WHEN RIGHT(CAST(Place as VARCHAR(20)), 1) = '1' then CAST(Place as VARCHAR(20)) + 'st'
        WHEN RIGHT(CAST(Place as VARCHAR(20)), 1) = '2' then CAST(Place as VARCHAR(20)) + 'nd'
        WHEN RIGHT(CAST(Place as VARCHAR(20)), 1) = '3' then CAST(Place as VARCHAR(20)) + 'rd'
        ELSE CAST(Place as VARCHAR(20)) + 'th'  
    END as Place
FROM
    RunnerTable
```

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't refresh to see Daves answer. But yea, same thing really.

Comment: I think your answer lacks support for the teens (11,12, and 13), which are weird. In your example you would get "11st"

Answer (score 2):

```
  DECLARE @Number int = 94
  SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@NUMBER) + CASE WHEN @Number % 100 IN (11, 12, 13) THEN 'th'
    ELSE 
        CASE @Number % 10
            WHEN 1 THEN 'st'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'nd'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'rd'
        ELSE 'th'
        END
    END
```

Comment: nice and simple. Like it. Stole it.

Answer (score 1):

**This Would be much better for any number**

```
 create Function dbo.fn_Numbers_Ordinal (@N as bigint) returns varchar(50) 
 as Begin
 Declare @a as varchar(50)= CAST(@N AS VARCHAR(50))
return(
SELECT  CAST(@N AS VARCHAR(50))
    +
    CASE
        WHEN Right(@a,2)='11' or Right(@a,2)='12' or Right(@a,2)='13'  Then 'th'
        WHEN @N % 10 = 1 THEN 'st'
        WHEN @N % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd'
        WHEN @N % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd'
        ELSE 'th' --for @N % 10 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
    END

)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figured I would add onto the various options. Here's a one-liner. I left this as a comment about a year ago. But someone suggested I submit it as an answer. So here ya go:

```
SELECT OrdinalRank = CONCAT(num, IIF(num % 100 IN (11,12,13),'th',COALESCE(CHOOSE(num % 10,'st','nd','rd'),'th')))
FROM (
    VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(10),(11),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(101),(102),(103)
) x(num)

--Result:
--1st
--2nd
--3rd
--4th
--5th
--10th
--11th
--20th
--21st
--22nd
--23rd
--24th
--101st
--102nd
--103rd
```

This takes advantage of the `IIF` and `CHOOSE` functions, which are only available in SQL 2012+.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @Number int = 113, 
        @Superscript int
IF @Number IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

```
IF LEN(@Number) >= 2
    SELECT @Superscript = RIGHT(@Number, 2)
ELSE
    SELECT @Superscript = RIGHT(@Number, 1)

SELECT @Number as Number,
 CASE WHEN @Superscript in (11,12,13) THEN 'th'
 ELSE CASE WHEN @Superscript = 1 THEN 'st'
                WHEN @Superscript = 2 THEN 'nd'
                WHEN @Superscript = 3 THEN 'rd'
                ELSE 'th'
      END 
END as Superscript
```

END ELSE 
    SELECT 0 as Number, 'th' as Superscript

Answer (score 0):

Another option to solve this with the FORMAT function (also you can display month names in other languages):

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS dayordinal ,'st' AS suffix
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS dayordinal ,'nd' AS suffix
UNION 
SELECT 3 AS dayordinal ,'rd' AS suffix

)

, YourTable AS --this is just for example
(SELECT CAST('1/1/2022' AS DATE) DateColumn
UNION 
SELECT CAST('1/14/2022' AS DATE) DateColumn
UNION 
SELECT CAST('4/4/2022' AS DATE) DateColumn
UNION 
SELECT CAST('2/2/2022' AS DATE) DateColumn
UNION 
SELECT CAST('3/13/2022' AS DATE) DateColumn
)

SELECT CAST(DATEPART(DAY, DateColumn) AS NVARCHAR(2))+ISNULL(c.suffix, 'th')+' '+ FORMAT(DateColumn, 'MMMM yyyy', 'fr-FR')
FROM YourTable t
LEFT JOIN cte c ON c.dayordinal=RIGHT(DATEPART(DAY, DateColumn),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have a need to spell out the ordinal in English, here is a piece of code that I altered from above. I use it as a piece of a string (description column) when a value in another column is a 1, 2, 10, 17, 99, etc.

```
;WITH CTE_Numbers
AS
(
    SELECT 1 num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1
    FROM CTE_Numbers
    WHERE num < 99
)

SELECT num,
    UPPER(
    case when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '2' then 'Twent'
        when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '3' then 'Thirt'
        when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '4' then 'Fort'
        when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '5' then 'Fift'
        when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '6' then 'Sixt'
        when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '7' then 'Sevent'
        when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '8' then 'Eight'
        when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '9' then 'Ninet'
        else ''
        end
    +
    case when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) <> '1' and right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) <> '0' then 'y-'
        else ''
        end
    +
    case when cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)) = '10' then 'Ten'
        when cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)) = '11' then 'Eleven'
        when cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)) = '12' then 'Twelf'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '1' then 'Fir'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '2' then 'Seco'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '3' then 'Thir'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '4' then 'Four'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '5' then 'Fif'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '6' then 'Six'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '7' then 'Seven'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '8' then 'Eigh'
        when right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '9' then 'Nin'
        when len(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10))) > 1 and left(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) <> '1' and right(cast(num AS VARCHAR(10)),1) = '0' then 'ie'
        end
    +
    case when num between 13 and 19 then 'teen' else '' end
    +
    CASE
        WHEN num % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th'
        WHEN num % 10 = 1 THEN 'st'
        WHEN num % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd'
        WHEN num % 10 = 3 THEN 'd'
        ELSE 'th'
    END
    ) as Ordinal_Long
FROM CTE_Numbers
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```