# How to get "Week of 2nd" based on date field in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2012

I have a `DueDate` column in my table and based on that date, I want to display the "Week of ..." value based on Monday date.

So I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you not want to display the full date? What do you want to happen when the start of the week is a different month? For example November 1st?

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers, e.g. `DateFromParts()`. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get week number in year from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794544/get-week-number-in-year-from-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172995/how-to-create-ordinal-numbers-i-e-1st-2nd-etc-in-sql) with the "DatePart" function like so:

```
SELECT  
        'Week Of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(DAY, (2-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())), GETDATE()) )) + CASE
                                                                      WHEN DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th' --first checks for exception
                                                                      WHEN DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) % 10 = 1 THEN 'st'
                                                                      WHEN DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd'                                                                                                              
                                                                      WHEN DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd'                                                                                                              
                                                                      ELSE 'th' --works for num % 10 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,0)                                                                                                         
                                                                    END
```

Comment: Thanks, but the` week of...` need to be based on Mondays. Like in a example

Comment: @Oleg I've edited my answer to match your question better

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: Aside: A more paranoid solution would take [`@@DateFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql) into account since it affects the `WeekDay` returned from [`DatePart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select date,
('week of ' + 
 convert(varchar(2), datepart(day, DATEADD(day, -(case when datepart(weekday, date)=1 then 8 else datepart(weekday, date) end)+2, date))))
as monday
from table1;
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4ff2/18).

<sub>This could be simpler if sunday is not considered the same as the last monday but the next</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you can use the DATEPART function to get the numeric day of the week, then build in a case statement to account for the Monday start... like this (where you'd substitute your date where I have '10/1/2017'):

```
select 'Week of ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(dd, -DATEPART(dw,'10/1/2017')
   + CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,'10/1/2017') = 1 THEN -5 ELSE 2 END, '10/1/2017'),101)
```

Edit: just realized my answer is effectively the same as Psidom's; yay slow typing.