# Show ID repetition with respect to month in SQL -- assign ordinal numbers to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to display a count number (ordinal number) of id with respect to month.
The ordinal number should only be provided if the INV value is greater then ZERO.

IF(INV > 0) for a given row, it will gain an ordinal number. 
The 1st row below has Zero inv, therefore it has null as a result. The
2nd row, as id-1 appears for the 1st time with inv > 0 it gives a result as 1st. And so-on with the following row, showing 2nd.
Same with id-2 came in the next row. It is showing result as 1st and so on.

Could you please advise how to achieve this in SQL.

```
ID  INV Dates   ExpectedResult
1   0   2017/01/01  Null
1   1   2017/02/01  1st
1   2   2017/03/01  2nd
2   5   2016/05/01  1st
3   10  2017/01/01  1st
2   0   2016/04/01  Null
5   2   2017/01/01  1st
2   5   2017/01/01  2nd
2   2   2017/10/01  3rd

Insert into abc values(1,0,2017/01/01)
Insert into abc values(1,1,2017/02/01)
Insert into abc values(1,2,2017/03/01)
Insert into abc values(2,5,2016/05/01)
Insert into abc values(3,10,2017/01/01)
Insert into abc values(2,0,2016/04/01)
Insert into abc values(5,2,2017/01/01)
Insert into abc values(2,5,2017/01/01)
Insert into abc values(2,2,2017/10/01)
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "1st row", unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Your data doesn't appear to have such a column.

Comment: I made some edits to make this clearer. As @GordonLinoff said, there is not implicit ordering in SQL, so I hope that an answerer will assume an ordering    by date (i.e. by month).

Comment: Also, in my edit, I introduce the term "ordinal number", that is numbers which imply order (not quantity). The answerer will probably provide them like "1", "2","3" instead of "1st","2nd","3rd". That is probably a better representation for a database.

Comment: If ordinal values are required [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173460/92546) answer may provide some horrifying clues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ID, DATEPART(year, Dates), DATEPART(month, Dates), COUNT(*)
from MY_TABLE
where INV > 0
group by ID, DATEPART(year, Dates), DATEPART(month, Dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with abc as
(
select
*
from (values
(1,0,'2017/01/01')
,(1,1,'2017/02/01')
,(1,2,'2017/03/01')
,(2,5,'2016/05/01')
,(3,10,'2017/01/01')
,(2,0,'2016/04/01')
,(5,2,'2017/01/01')
,(2,5,'2017/01/01')
,(2,2,'2017/10/01')
) a(ID ,  INV , Dates )
)
select
*
,case when inv=0 then null else
row_number() over (partition by id,case when inv=0 then null else 1 end order by dates) 
end nr
from abc
order by id,dates
```

You have to add a function to convert from 1,2,3 to 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc

see for instance:

[How to create ordinal numbers (i.e. "1st" "2nd", etc.) in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172995/how-to-create-ordinal-numbers-i-e-1st-2nd-etc-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select *,  
    CASE WHEN INV > 0 THEN 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ( CASE WHEN INV > 0 THEN ID END ) ORDER BY Dates, INV )  
    END ExpectedResult 
from abc
```