# SQL Server : count number of rows per hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table with 2628 rows in it. I want to get a count per hour. I have a `completion_time` column which tells the date time of per record.

[image]

I can find only one-hour count.

```
select count(*) 
from billing b 
where b.completion_time >= '2019-04-16 23:50:23' 
  and b.completion_time <='2019-04-17 00:50:22'
```

The date time is up to 9 hours. i.e. the process was started at `2016-04-16 23:50:23` and it ends on `2019-04-17 08:16:49`. So I want total counts per hour.

**Update 1**

I want output like below

[image]

How can I achieve it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any `group by` clause?

Comment: @qxg group by is giving pe records per minutes

Comment: the `1st hour`, `2nd hour` etc is based on which column and with relative to what time ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select datepart(hour,b.completion_time) Hour, count(*) NumberOfRecords
from billing b
group by datepart(hour,b.completion_time)
```

**Edit:**

```
select  row_number() over (order by min(b.completion_time)) RowNumber, count(*) NumberOfRecords
from billing b
group by datepart(hour,b.completion_time)
order by min(b.completion_time)
```

Comment: `datepart(hour,b.completion_time)` gives me '0,23,3,6,7,1,4,5,2,8'. These are number of hours ?

Comment: Yes, `datepart(hour, b.completion_time)` gives you the `hour` in the `select`

Comment: so `23` is the hour ?

Comment: @Faisal Yes, It is.

Comment: I want result like this '1st hour, 2nd hour, 3rd hour, 4th hour,........,nth hour'

Comment: I am confused :(

Comment: Do you mean that instead of the hour itself, you want to get its order number in the select output?

Comment: yes but it should be per hour like it shows the count of 1st hour, 2nd hour and so on

Comment: You can use following code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172995/how-to-create-ordinal-numbers-i-e-1st-2nd-etc-in-sql) to ad "st", "nd', "th"...

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    Declare @StartTime DATETIME = '2016-04-16 23:50:23'
    Declare @EndTime DateTime = '2019-04-17 08:16:49'

    Declare @Tab Table(id int, Completion_Time DateTime)

    Insert into @Tab
    SELECT 1, '2016-04-16 23:50:23' Union All
    SELECT 2,'2016-04-17 00:50:24' Union All
    SELECT 3,'2016-04-17 01:50:26' Union All
    SELECT 4,'2016-04-17 01:50:32' Union All
    SELECT 5,'2016-04-17 01:50:55' Union All
    SELECT 6,'2016-04-17 02:50:28' Union All
    SELECT 7,'2016-04-17 02:50:30' Union All
    SELECT 8,'2016-04-17 02:50:45' Union All
    SELECT 9,'2016-04-17 04:50:32' Union All
    SELECT 10,'2016-04-17 04:50:52' 

    --Select Id, DATEDIFF(HH,@StartTime,Completion_Time) Diff from @Tab

    ;with cte
    As
    (

        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF(HH,@StartTime,Completion_Time)+1) as [Hour] , COUNT(*) As [Records]
        From @Tab
        Group by DATEDIFF(HH,@StartTime,Completion_Time)+1
    )

    Select  [Hour] + CASE
                WHEN [Hour] % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th'
                WHEN [Hour] % 10 = 1 THEN 'st'
                WHEN [Hour] % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd'
                WHEN [Hour] % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd'
                ELSE 'th' 
            END + ' hour',
        Records
    from cte
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do just what you need :

```
 SELECT HOUR(b.completion_time) hourOfDay, COUNT(*) NumberOfRecords
 FROM billing b 
 GROUP BY hourOfDay
```

`HOUR` is a predefined function to calculate hour from a `DateTime`.

Comment: I am getting this error `'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: try  DATEPART in place of HOUR