# Convert getdate to format 22nd APR, 2022

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please help me with this,
How can I convert getdate() to format 22**nd** APR, 2022,
21**st** APR, 2022,
23**rd** APR,2022,
24**th** APR, 2022,
nd or th or rd is important here.

So far I have done this,

**SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'dd MMM, yyyy') as date**

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: see also: [How to create ordinal numbers (i.e. "1st" "2nd", etc.) in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172995/how-to-create-ordinal-numbers-i-e-1st-2nd-etc-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQLServer:

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(),'d'
+IIF(DAY(getdate()) IN (1,21,31),'''st'''
,IIF(DAY(getdate()) IN (2,22),'''nd'''
,IIF(DAY(getdate()) IN (3,23),'''rd''','''th''')))
+' MMM' +', '+ 'yyyy') As [Formatted Date]
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9a97ee78e1325169aa4ae8f4058511b)

Comment: This does not work correctly if you only change the date in the 1st line of your query, you always have to change every occurence of the date. The goal should be you only have to provide the input date once.

Comment: Hi @JonasMetzler, thanks for your input on when it will not work but please tell me where does the OP say that ? "Convert getdate to format 22nd APR, 2022" ? Why do you downvote something that works ??? Downvote means that the answer is not useful. This answer is more than useful...  Please check your guidelines...

Comment: Sorry, the down vote was a mistake. I will remove it again. Anyway, although the OP doesn't say it, I would think your solution would be better when changing as I proposed. But of course, it is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a query like below

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'd'''+v.suff+''' MMM, yyyy') as date
FROM
(values (1,'st'), (2,'nd'),(3,'rd'), (4,'th')
, (5,'th'), (6,'th'), (7,'th'), (8,'th')
, (9,'th'), (0,'th'))v(num,suff)
WHERE DAY(getdate())%10=v.num
```

[Demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d213f45da8f259decc8f07fb61d8c207)

Answer (score 0):

This one cover the 11th,12th and 13th.

```
select 
cast(day(getdate()) as nvarchar)+ 
case when day(getdate()) in (11,12,13)
    then 'th'
else
case right(day(getdate()),1)
        when 1 then
            'st'
        when 2 then 
            'nd'
        when 3 then
         'rd'
        else 'th'
    end
end + format(getdate(),' MMM yyyy') as suffixed
```

Answer (score 0):

I would perform this formatting at the presentation tier - reporting tools, client languages like C# and PHP, etc. all have more elaborate and efficient date formatting methods than T-SQL.

If it has to be done in T-SQL, I would avoid `FORMAT()` because it's [slow](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) [as](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7144/sql-date-format-comparison-sql-format-sql-convert/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) [molasses](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7145/sql-date-format-comparison-computed-column-materialized-column/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and since, presumably, you're going to call this more than once or for sets, I would put it in an inline table-valued function which will be more efficient than a scalar UDF and much more maintainable than putting this conditional logic inline. Using the `CASE` expression from [the accepted answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30195443/61305):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SpecificFormat(@d date)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    WITH s(d) AS 
    (
      SELECT REPLACE(UPPER(CONVERT(varchar(13), @d, 106)),' ','.')
    ),
    p(d,m,y) AS
    (
      SELECT PARSENAME(d,3), PARSENAME(d,2), PARSENAME(d,1)
      FROM s
    )
    SELECT OutputFormat = CONCAT_WS(' ', d + CASE 
      WHEN d % 100 IN (11,12,13) THEN 'th'
      WHEN d % 10 = 1 THEN 'st'
      WHEN d % 10 = 2 THEN 'nd'
      WHEN d % 10 = 3 THEN 'rd'
      ELSE 'th' END, m + ',', y)
    FROM p
  );
```

Examples:

```
DECLARE @d date = getdate();
SELECT OutputFormat FROM dbo.SpecificFormat(@d);
```

Output:

> | OutputFormat |
> | --- |
> | 22nd APR, 2022 |

```
SELECT o.name, f.OutputFormat
  FROM sys.objects AS o
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SpecificFormat(o.modify_date) AS f;
```

Output:

> | name | OutputFormat |
> | --- | --- |
> | SpecificFormat | 22nd APR, 2022 |
> | QueryNotificationErrorsQueue | 13th APR, 2009 |
> | queue_messages_1977058079 | 24th SEP, 2019 |
> | ... | ... |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c0a4f270dbc6356f19b82dec1a1d2cb)