# Date Formatting in SSRS(with ordinal indicator)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

How to get following format(with ordinal indicator) in SSRS?

Example:

> 12th Dec 2017

Comment: Comment from BishNaboB has the right answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712572/format-datetime-day-with-st-nd-rd-th

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text box properties and set a custom style like this:
[image]

For more information on formatting textboxes, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207048.aspx

Comment: I am not convinced i can get it this way. I need to have (auto)ordinal date(example 3rd, if date is 3) ,month in 3 alphabets( example Dec) and year in 4 digits(example 2017).

Comment: This might help more then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712572/format-datetime-day-with-st-nd-rd-th